# next auth google login get custom token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am using next js, next auth and a custom backend (flask), where I am using API Endpoint secured with jwt token.
In the next js frontend I want to access this jwt token with the useSession hook to make requests to this API Endpoints. With the CredentialsProvider everything works fine. I was able to register and login a user and can get access the jwt token. When I am using useSession with credentials login, I have the data in the following format, which is what i want (token.sub is my jwt access token) :

```
{
    "data": {
        "session": {
            "user": {},
            "expires": "2023-02-06T21:35:50.296Z"
        },
        "token": {
            "sub": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTY3MzEyNzM1MCwianRpIjoiZDJmODIwZjAtOGYxOS00Y2Q5LTk0Yxxxxxxx",
            "iat": 1673127350,
            "exp": 1675719350,
            "jti": "53b9fcaa-3aa9-4567-9381-341231144e72"
        }
    },
    "status": "authenticated"
}
```

however when I use the google login I am getting this format:
All I want is to get the jwt access token from my backend.

```
{
    "data": {
        "session": {
            "user": {
                "name": "google name",
                "email": "google email",
                "image": "google pic"
            },
            "expires": "2023-02-06T21:24:09.905Z"
        },
        "token": {
            "name": "google user name",
            "email": "google email",
            "picture": "google pic",
            "sub": "115092xxxxxxx",
            "iat": 16731xxxx,
            "exp": 1675xxxx6,
            "jti": "1fc246fa-xxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "status": "authenticated"
}
```

This is the code for next-auth. To get the access with google login I added the signIn callback and add there the request to my backend to get the jwt access token.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import API from "../../../API";
import axiosHandler from "../../../axios-handler";


const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
        const loginResponse = await axiosHandler.post(credentials.isRegister? API.REGISTER :API.LOGIN, credentials)
        if(loginResponse.data){
          return {
            id: loginResponse.data.token,
            token: loginResponse.data.token,            
          }
        }
        return null
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      return {session, user, token}
    },

    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token
    },
    async signIn({user, account}){
      if(account?.provider ==="google"){
        const googleAuthData = {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          image: user.image,
          authProvider: 'google',
          password: ''
      }
      const loginResponse = await axiosHandler.post(API.LOGIN, 
        {
          name: googleAuthData.name, 
          email: googleAuthData.email, 
          secretKey:"xxx"})
      if(loginResponse.data){
        return {
          ...user,
          id: loginResponse.data.token,
          token: loginResponse.data.token
        }
      }
      }
      return user
      
    }
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a close similar challenge, in my case the backend needs the userId to validate the accessToken coming from the nextAuth. however thats not possible. My flow is slightly different from yours as am relying on the next auth for generating the jwt, while I ensure that the backend uses the same TOKEN_SECRET and algorithm used by the backend to generate the jwt.

**NB**: *I used the same JWT algorithm and Secret on both frontend and backend*

I think for your use case, you might have to customize the `jwt.encode` function, to make an API request to your backend and then return the access token provided from the backend

```
jwt: {
 ...,
 encode: async (data: any) => {
   const { secret, token } = data;
   const { email, picture, name } = token;

   // make an API call
   // set the encodedToken with accessToken from BE

   return encodedToken;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have trick like that to pass access token from oauth google
i set id_token to user.name

```
 async signIn({ user, account }) {
  user.name = account!.id_token;
  user.email = account!.provider;
  return true;
},
```

and call api in async jwt and it work fine

```
async jwt({ token, user }) {
  if (user) {
    try {
      const data: ResLogin = await CodeSmoothApi.login_social({
        id_token: user.name,
        social: user.email || 'google',
      }).then((res) => {
        return res.data; // return the data from the server response (token, user) as a object (token, user) with the type ResLogin
      });

      if (data) {
        const { access_token: accessToken, refresh_token: refreshToken } = data.token; // We get the access token and the refresh token from the data object.
      }
      console.log('data', data);
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log('error', e);
    }
    return {
      ...token,
      user,
    };
  }
  return token;
},
```